# MySql Query to get friend list from Friends table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named friends with following structure:

```
id, from_id, to_id, confirmed, ....
```

This table contains the list of all friends of all users. The from_id and to_id contain ids of the users where from_id is the one who actually sent the friend request.

Now, I need to select the list of all the friends of a particular user into.

Is is better to do it using the following query or a query with union:

```
"select (from_id + to_id)- $user_id as friend_id, ... from friends where from_id=$user_id or to_id=$user_id"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I love your mathematic-fan solution I think it is not considering overflow issues. For example: what would happen if you add two extremely big numbers?

Apart from that, your solution relies on a numeric user_id. Using a union might take a bit more (you should test that to make sure) but will work with any data type.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `union` (make sure you have indexes on `from_id` and `to_id`):

```
select from_id from friends where to_id = $user_id
union
select to_id from friends where from_id = $user_id
```

It's more clear this way in my opinion.

Comment: How should I make sure  I have indexes on from_id and to_id?

Comment: Create an index on each of them. Take a look at `create index` sentence in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have keys on the ids the union will certainly be better, then performing the arithmetic operations.